# Disable file name change when downloading private files

Tags: 6, files

I'm using drupal 6. When user is downloading file from my website name of the file is changed to "download" on chrome (in firefox it is just random string) and only when file is image or pdf file extension is provided (for example word and excel files are without extensions). Is it possible to "keep" file name and extension as it was saved on server?

For file management i'm using [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce/releases/6.x-2.6) module (imce-6.x-2.6).

Comment: There are probably a hundred ways that Drupal can offer files for download, so it really depends on your particular setup. Please modify your question and give examples of what kind of files are creating this behavior, and also which modules you have installed that provide the downloads in the first place.